# @Autowired dependency in custom Spring Data Repository is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I created a custom Spring Data repository like this

```
BaseRepositoryCustomImpl<T extends BaseEntity>
    extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, Long>
    implements BaseEntityRepository<T, Long> {
     @Autowired
     private MyCustomClass myCustomClass;
}
```

Note that `MyCustomClass` is defined in my config class as `@Bean`. Then use my custom repository by adding it to my config class like this

```
@Configuration
@Profile("jpa")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.package.repository"
}, repositoryImplementationPostfix = "CustomImpl",
   repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryCustomImpl.class
)
```

Everything is working okay except for the `myCustomClass`, which is always `null`. How should I autowire `MyCustomClass`? It is auto-wiring properly if used in other classes like Controllers.

Comment: Please add the MyCustomClass declaration and the stack trace.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am interested in solution as well

Answer (score 0):

More generic problem is how to autowire instances for not spring managed types.

you can create BeanUtil class

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

and then use it the following way to get bean:

```
    UserRepository userRepository = BeanUtil.getBean(UserRepository.class);
```

inspired by [this](https://codippa.com/how-to-autowire-objects-in-non-spring-classes/)